# ProgrammingError: 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost when using mysql.connector in python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector-python

On my linux mint 20 cinnamon, I've installed mariadb using `sudo apt install mariadb`. And when I want to connect to mysql in the terminal, I just run `sudo ystemctl start mariadb`
and connect using`sudo mysql -u root`without password and everything works just fine.
But when I try connecting using this python script in vscode, I get the error mentioned in the title:

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='test')
cnx.close()
```

I haven't set any passwords for anything. why isn't it giving me access now?
And believe me when I say I haven't done anything wrog!I literally just install mariadb and the only thing I've done is create the test database and table people

Comment: Hmm. That is strange behavior. In some distributives random password created when first install (even if you not set it manually). Try to check `grep -i password /var/log/mysqld.log`

Answer (score 0):

1. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql

use this link and create one user and then you can try to set username and password in this script and you will be able to connect it.

2. For the root user, You have to set a password by ALter user role and set the same password in the script and u will be able to connect the mysql.